# Is it proper to say "don't let the error messages clobber up the results"?

Tags: vocabulary

I think I heard expressions such as "so many error messages... clobbering up the results", meaning we might expect to see some results on a computer terminal (such as in a command prompt), but the error messages is messing up the results, making the results difficult to see among the large amount of error messages.

But I can't find such definition of "clobber up". Does it have a proper meaning of "messing up"?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use *messing up* as a native speaker:

> so many error messages... **messing up** the results

This would be appropriate as *messing up* is [defined as](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mess+up):

> A cluttered, untidy, usually dirty place or condition

In this case, the command prompt is untidy and full of error messages.

**I found [the definitions for clobber](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clobber), and could not find one that matched.**

Comment: hacker terms might have "clobber" meaning overwriting something: https://www.eps.mcgill.ca/jargon/jargon.html#clobber and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452865/are-there-any-disadvantages-of-setting-noclobber but I wonder if "overwriting something" can mean messing up the results